# With Mongoid, can I "update_all" to push a value onto an array field for multiple entries at once?

Tags: ruby, arrays, mongodb, mongoid, update-all

Using Mongoid, is it possible to use "update_all" to push a value onto an array field for all entries matching a certain criteria?

Example:

```
class Foo
  field :username
  field :bar, :type => Array

  def update_all_bars
    array_of_names = ['foo','bar','baz']
    Foo.any_in(username: foo).each do |f|
      f.push(:bar,'my_new_val')
    end
  end
end
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to update all the users at once (to push the value 'my_new_val' onto the "foo" field for each matching entry) using "update_all" (or something similar) instead of looping through them to update them one at a time. I've tried everything I can think of and so far no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need call that from the Mongo DB Driver. You can do :

```
Foo.collection.update( 
  Foo.any_in(username:foo).selector, 
  {'$push' => {bar: 'my_new_val'}},
  {:multi => true}
)
```

Or

```
Foo.collection.update( 
  {'$in' => {username: foo}}, 
  {'$push' => {bar: 'my_new_val'}},
  {:multi => true}
)
```

You can do a pull_request or a feature request if you want that in Mongoid builtin.

Comment: Was just writing the answer, there should also be a third parameter `multi: true`

Comment: What's this ``:multi => true`` for?

Comment: @shingara here you are: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102942/mongodb-mongoid-what-does-multi-true-mean