# Mongodb/Mongoid - what does {:multi => true} mean

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

Regarding this question: [With Mongoid, can I "update_all" to push a value onto an array field for multiple entries at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637728/with-mongoid-can-i-update-all-to-push-a-value-onto-an-array-field-for-multipl/9645603#comment12940146_9645603)

I would like to ask:

1. What's the purpose of `{:multi => true}` here?
2. Is it possible to push a value into an array when `update_all` via mongoid now? because the question is  in 2010.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation for the [MongoDB update method](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-update%28%29) states the following:

> *multi* - indicates if all documents matching criteria should be updated rather than just one. Can be useful with the $ operators below.

So basically the `multi` parameter is what enables the `update_all` behaviour in the question you linked to.

In answer to your second question: yes - Mongoid has this feature built in now. The documentation reference is [here](http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/modification.html). But you can use it like this:

```
User.where(:gender => "Male").update_all(:title => "Mr")
```

**Update**

In the case where you want to push a value onto an array field, you'll still need to use the MongoDB library directly, since the Mongoid `update_all` method only supports the `$set` database update method (which can be used to update an entire array, but not push values onto it).

The example in the answer to the question you linked to would work, I have copied it below those who stumble across this question (thanks [shingara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285289/shingara)!):

```
User.collection.update( 
  {'$in' => {:gender => 'Male'}}, 
  {'$push' => {:titles => 'Mr'}},
  {:multi => true}
)
```

Comment: Thanks @theTRON, for question 2: you showed to update a plain field, is it also possible to use it to push a value into an array field?

Comment: The Mongoid docs mention that it uses the `$set` method - which sets the value of a field. So you'll have to the MongoDB library - i've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks, so that means is still using this way. :)

Answer (score 1):

A particular usecase is when the Mongodb is sharded (http://docs.mongodb.org/master/MongoDB-sharding-guide.pdf). Specifically on update over a sharded mongo collection,when I used an identifier other than _id, the update failed. I had to set multi as true and then it updated all the documents across various shards.